# Can't Get ProxyPass User IP Address

Tags: javascript, php, apache, websocket

JAVASCRIPT

```
websocket = new WebSocket("wss://site.com/game_play/");
....
```

PHP

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
....
$size=socket_recvfrom($socket_new,$input,65535,0,$ipaddress,$port);
echo "Received [$input] ($size bytes) from IP $ipaddress Port $port\n";
```

APACHE

```
ProxyPass /game_play/ ws://site.com:8090/server.php
ProxyPassReverse /game_play/ ws://site.com:8090/server.php
```

START SERVER - SSH: php server.php

Error: User ip address should be returned; server ip address is returning.

Note: Returns X-FORWARDED-FOR in the header. However, this is not safe.

If I'm not wrong, they said that RemoteIPHeader ( mod_remoteip ) would be the solution. But I think I made a mistake, it didn't work even though I tried.

Thanks