# Reverse Proxy - Get User IP - PHP,APACHE

Tags: php, apache, cpanel, reverse-proxy

JAVASCRIPT

`websocket = new WebSocket("wss://site.com/game_play/");.....`

PHP

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
....
$size=socket_recvfrom($socket_new,$input,65535,0,$ipaddress,$port);
echo "Received [$input] ($size bytes) from IP $ipaddress Port $port\n";
```

APACHE

```
ProxyPass /game_play/ ws://site.com:8090/server.php
ProxyPassReverse /game_play/ ws://site.com:8090/server.php
```

START SERVER - SSH: php server.php

**Error:** User ip address should be returned; server ip address is returning.

**Note:** Returns X-FORWARDED-FOR in the header. However, this is not safe.

THANKS.

Comment: Is this different from your other question? [Can't Get ProxyPass User IP Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68402478/cant-get-proxypass-user-ip-address) - Please rather edit your existing question than asking again with minimal change.

Comment: @Olaf Kock Same part. However, I don't think I made a mistake. I still haven't found a solution.